# Can anyone identify this Parallel to Serial Interface Board?

Tags: 6809, identify-this-card

I just spent an enjoyable day at the local ham fest with my father - digging through boxes of other peoples junk.  I'm a sucker for weird electronics, especially when it's in the free pile, and so I am now the proud owner of two Parallel to Serial interface boards and I'm left wondering what they originally came out of.

The boards are populated with some intriguing chips (which is why I nabbed them); assuming my quick googling is correct - an EF6809P (an 8-bit MC6809 CPU), an EF6850P ACIA, three EF6821P PIAs, and an AMD AM9128-20PC static RAM.

So obviously the chip complement seems to support the board label as some kind of a parallel to serial interface, but to what?  Below are some snapshots to hopefully help identify the board.

First a view of the component side of the board (note the 50 pin connector J4)
[image: component side]

Next, the assembly number and board description (sorry for the lack of definition here, the camera simply wouldn't pick up the silver grey lettering)
[image: board description and assembly number]

The CPU, ACIA, RAM, one PIA an an <s>unidentified chip (26A1063/A)</s> AM2716DC EPROM.
[image: chips]

And finally, the edge of the board (probably 2 RS-232? and 1 Parallel?)
[image: connectors]

So, anyone having any brain-waves?

Comment: Looks like a full-blown computer rather than just an interface. The labelled chip is most likely an EPROM. The logo is vaguely familiar, too

Comment: The [EF6809P](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=290929&part-number=EF6809P) is a 6809 CPU, not a 6800. Those are very different, and that will be especially important if there's a ROM there to disassemble, as U32 appears to be.

Comment: Since based on the socket size, use and configuration U32 appears to be a ROM, I would start by dumping that. (You can do that quite easily with an Arduino.) Start by scanning it for strings, remembering to clear all the high bits for that scan, and that alone may tell you exactly what the board is.

Comment: @Curt, good idea on dumping the rom.  I was thinking about that too - when I get around to it.  As for the 6809, the wiki article says the 6809 is 'source compatible' with the 6800 - which on closer inspection means the assembler would accept 6800 source and producer 6809 ML (working around the reduced instruction set of the 6809).  So I guess the 6809 and 6800 are in the same general wheelhouse, but the 09 isn't a 'drop in' replacement for a 6800...

Comment: If there’s a possibility it’s a whole computer, maybe try connecting a terminal to each of the serial ports and check for a prompt?

Comment: Identify this will be hard. Single board computers (as this seems to be) were made of 'everyone'. There is a big chance the company that made it disappeared in the late 80s or early 90s.

Comment: @Geo... Yes, the 6809 is "compatible" with the 6800 like the 8088 is "compatible" with the 8080 (with the exception that the address width was not increased): in other words it's a far more powerful next-generation CPU preserving parts of the previous generation's architecture. Also, the 6809 has considerably more opcodes than the 6800; "reduced instruction set" would refer to having fewer assembler mnemonics, which would be due to more orthogonal addressing modes and the particular choices made in mapping assembly mnemonics to opcodes.

Comment: It's seems likely to me that it is in fact a "Parallel to Serial In" board, what it seems to say in the second picture.  It would have been used to connect serial printers to computers with parallel interfaces.

Comment: So, any luck with the ROM dump? It can be done [quite easily with an Arduino](http://www.msarnoff.org/eprom/), and you need not even pull the ROM from the board if you wire up a [DIP test clip](https://www.mouser.com/Test-Measurement/Test-Equipment-Accessories/Test-Clips/_/N-7uqds?P=1yyx2rl).

Comment: @Curt, Actually I'd never dumped a ROM before and thought it would be fun to give it a go last week - so I coded up a sketch, wired up the EPROM and dumped the data to a file.  I did not find any ASCII text, and so for completeness I also tried disassembling the file using f9dasm  (https://github.com/Arakula/f9dasm).  The resulting disassembly _looks_ legit - but hasn't really helped me to identify the maker or equipment that the board originated from.  When I get some time, I'd will take a second look at my wiring/code to check for any mistakes, but I think I'm stuck with a mystery.

Comment: It's not unknown for some systems to store ASCII with the high bit set on some or all characters. Did you try running `strings` or similar on a copy of the ROM binary with the high bit of every byte cleared? I also have made [a patch for f9dasm](https://github.com/Arakula/f9dasm/pull/8) that better displays such areas when marked as `char` in the disassembly config.

Comment: Also, making the binary available might help. If you don't want to make it publicly available, you can send me email (my address is in [my profile](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/7208/curt-j-sampson?tab=profile)) and I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: @Curt, I did not run strings, that's an interesting thought. - And yes, I was going to make the binary available as soon as I had some confidence that my EPROM dump wasn't boneheaded in some way and the data is correct.  I'm pretty sure I got it right, but I was going to carefully go over everything before embarrassing myself publicly.  LOL.  I'll drop you an email with what I have so far.  Thx for the interest!

Comment: Hi ... I've done lots of work with 6809, happy to have a look at the binary if that helps.  Also: I remember a British mainframe GEC 63 from the 1980s which used 6809s as embedded controllers to drive the 8-port RS-232 board.  So yours is perhaps something like that.  The big D-type is a challenge though.  Any chance of a hires image so we can read the small chips?

Comment: @RossRidge A processor and ROM seem overkill for _just_ a parallel to serial converter. Years back I built such a beast for a TRS-80 clone using little more than a [6403 UART](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp8/cmos8/_dataSheets/IM6402.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: @TripeHound Turns out its overkill used to connect a bunch of LEDs and/or switches.

Comment: @TripeHound In my updated answer I discuss the overkill thing. It was clear when disassembling the code that the system was overkill for this particular board, but it's also clear that they're reusing code and probably hardware used for other products as well, which would explain why they didn't do a complete _de novo_ design just to save on the BOM. Also keep in mind that the final product is a low-volume item being sold only to companies spending a lot more on the other equipment that this is connected to.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson As you say, it needs more than just a "dumb" UART+74xx, so it's not as much overkill as I first thought. Brilliant detective work, BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boards are essentially "serial to parallel converters," but
probably not of any type anybody here is familiar with. A
[manual](http://www.steampoweredradio.com/pdf/moseley/manuals/Moseley%20MRC-2%20Microprocessor%20Remote%20Control%20System%20Manual%20Volume%202.pdf) has been found that describes two devices, the MSD-1
Multiple Status Display and the MDC-2 Multiple Direct Command Option,
used with the Moseley Associates Inc. MRC-2 system, a
microprocessor-based system for monitoring and control of equipment
such as radio and TV transmitters.

#### Hardware

The board is a fairly basic SBC, with a 6809 CPU, 2 KB ROM, 2 KB RAM,
a 6850 ACIA for serial input and some parallel I/O.

On one of the DB-25 connectors the the system receives RS-232 serial
input at 300 or 1200 bps (based on the switch setting). I am guessing
that this serial signalling is passed through (via hardware, not an
ACIA) to the other DB-25 connector for connection to further similar
boards so that they can see the same data stream. The firmware itself
never generates any serial output.

The board's output is 32 digital signals on the DB-37 connector.
Presumably these signals were used to control something, but there's
no indication of what. The output is handled by a pair of 6821 PIAs,
U25 and U26, together referred to as "P32" in the disassembly.

There is a third PIA, U27 ("P16" in the disassembly) that is used for
things like reading the switches and signalling that the system is
alive and/or restarting.

#### Function

The board receives a stream of characters on the serial port and,
based on what it receives, sets bits on the 32-bit digital output.
This appears to be designed so that one stream of serial data can be
passed to multiple boards; each one has an address from 0-15 (probably
set by the rotary switch) that determines which characters it will
take as commands to change its digital output and which it will
ignore.

The protocol is not like anything I've seen before and is probably
proprietary. It's not a simple case of specific characters toggling
specific bits on the digital output (e.g., "set bit 5"), but instead
there's some sort of obscure processing determining how the outputs
are set.

Without knowing the purpose of the board the protocol itself doesn't
seem terribly interesting, but you can read through the state machine
code that processes the input and updates the output if you want to
start to dig into the details.

#### Alternative Designs

As Ross Ridge mentions in the comments on the question, yes, this
board is a bit overkill on the hardware side. The hardware couldn't
reasonably be as simple as just an ACIA and 74xx logic, given that it
needs to interpret (and, for the switch unit, generate) a standard
serial protocol used by various other devices, but certainly cheaper
CPU, RAM and PIA options could have been used.

From the filename of the catalogue below, the system was designed no
later than 1981. I probably would have suggested a [6508](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502#Variations_and_derivatives)
microprocessor, which included 256 bytes of RAM (plenty for this
application) and an 8-bit PIA. Five bits of the PIA would be used for
input from the switches and the other three for shift registers
(74LS595 or similar) for the data outputs and switch inputs. Using
pricing from an [advert in the February 1981 issue of BYTE
Magazine](https://archive.org/details/eu_BYTE-1981-02_OCR/page/n374), this would have replaced the $38 6809 with
an MPU possibly even cheaper than the $12 6502 and completely dropped
three 6821 PIAs at $6.50 each, for something like a $50 saving on the
BOM.

That said, I suspect that these boards were used in other (possibly
more sophisticated) designs as well, and the code is clearly re-using
parts of a standard framework for more sophisticated systems. (See how
the interrupt-handling code works, for example.) So it's probably not
unreasonable to re-use existing, tested resources even at the cost of
a more expensive BOM.

#### Resources

The [MRC-1 Catalogue](http://www.steampoweredradio.com/pdf/moseley/catalogs/Moseley%20MRC-1%20Remote%20Control%20Brochure%20March%201981.pdf) gives an overview of the full system in
which the accessories containing these boards were used. [MRC 2
Microprocessor Remote Control System, Volume One](http://www.steampoweredradio.com/pdf/moseley/manuals/Moseley%20MRC-2%20Microprocessor%20Remote%20Control%20System%20Manual%20Volume%201.pdf) is the
manual for that system, and [MRC 2 Microprocessor Remote Control
Options, Volume Two](http://www.steampoweredradio.com/pdf/moseley/manuals/Moseley%20MRC-2%20Microprocessor%20Remote%20Control%20System%20Manual%20Volume%202.pdf) is the manual for the products that used
these boards. You can see a picture of an installation including the
MRC 2 and these two options (at the lower right) at [Alice@97.3
Transmitter](http://www.steampoweredradio.com/New%20Tour/alice/fmx4.html).

The [rcse-mystery-board](https://gitlab.com/retroabandon/rcse-mystery-board.git) repository on GitLab contains
high-resolution photos of the board, a dump of the ROMs (two, since
they were somewhat different between the two examples of this board) a
disassembler and framework to run it, and an info file for the
disassember that produces a very heavily commented, but not entirely
complete, [disassembly of one ROM](https://gitlab.com/retroabandon/rcse-mystery-board/-/blob/master/PS-1.dis). (There's also a bit of
disassembly of the other ROM, particularly the common parts.)

The README gives details of what's there and how to use the tools, and
if you walk foward through the commit history from the start you'll
see how I built the tools and did the disassembly, step by step. (The
commit messages generally contain detailed commentary on this.)

Comment: If you google for ASSY 20D2844 you get one single result. It's a PDF file here : http://www.steampoweredradio.com/pdf/moseley/manuals/Moseley%20MRC-2%20Microprocessor%20Remote%20Control%20System%20Manual%20Volume%202.pdf

Comment: @Scott, your google-foo is strong.  I never found that PDF, but scanning through it briefly reveals a diagram on page 3-22 that looks very much like the mystery board.  I did indeed pick up the boards at a HAM fest, so that reinforces the idea the board served some purpose related to radio.  I'm looking forward to digesting the PDF in greater detail.  Thanks for the great find!

Comment: Curt did an amazing job digging into the board and puzzling around it's secrets.  I just wanted to send him a warm thank-you for all his effort.   It was great fun dumping the ROMS and taking some pics so he could go all-in trying to figure this thing out.

Comment: @ScottEarle I just got a chance to skim through that PDF and, yeah, that looks like it all right. I wish I'd had the Google-fu to find that when I'd started my analysis! (I'll grab a copy of that document and commit it to the repo tomorrow, and update the README.)

Comment: Based on the manual Scott Earle linked the board is used in either the MSD-1 Multiple Status Display or MDC-2 Multiple Direct Command option chassis. The two serial ports are for daisy chaining these units, one port is the upstream connection the other is the downstream connection. The internal 50-pin connector is used to connect to a front panel module of either 32 LEDs (MSD-1) or 16 switches and 16 LEDs (MDC-2). The external 37-pin "parallel" port receives the state of these LEDs/switches, and isn't an Centronics printer port.

Comment: @RossRidge The OP has two boards, nearly identical except for the ROMs, one clearly for the MSD-1 and the other for the MSD-2. I've updated my answer (and the repo) in light of the manual.

Comment: Oh, and in case anybody else is considering answering questions like this, the upvotes per hour spent on the answer ratio for this is more than an order of magnitude worse than any other question I've ever answered, on any StackExchange. :-)

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Except that people who _can_ answer questions like this do so _just because they can_! Any UV/H is just a bonus.